dockerでMySQLコンテナを起動しようとするとExited (1)でコンテナが起動しない
さくらVPSでOSのubuntuを新規にインストールしDockerを入れました。
MySQLコンテナを起動しましたが「Exited (1)」で止まってしまいます。動くようにするにはどうしたらいいですか。下記コンテナ起動コマンドをWindowsのdokcerデスクトップで実行すると「Exited (1)」にならず起動できます。
もし原因がわかりましたら、ご教示お願いします。
●各バージョン
Ubuntu 20.04 amd64
Docker 20.10.24, build 297e128
mysqlイメージ 8.0.37、8.4、8.0-debian
●インストール手順
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
●コンテナ起動コマンド
docker run -it --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456789 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql

●docker logs
2024-06-19 13:05:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.37-1.el9 started.
2024-06-19 13:05:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-06-19 13:05:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.37-1.el9 started.
2024-06-19 13:05:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2024-06-19T13:05:54.789675Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2024-06-19T13:05:54.790106Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37) initializing of server in progress as process 78
2024-06-19T13:05:54.800700Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-19T13:05:55.439450Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-06-19T13:05:57.583392Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2024-06-19 13:06:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2024-06-19 13:06:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
mysqld will log errors to /var/lib/mysql/1f22df600987.err
2024-06-19T13:06:03.427686Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011065] [Server] Unable to determine if daemon is running: Function not implemented (rc=0).
2024-06-19T13:06:03.428094Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
2024-06-19 13:06:03+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Unable to start server.


mysqld のログも見ないと詳細わからないでしょう。ログ内に書いてある通り  /var/lib/mysql/1f22df600987.err ファイル内容も見てください。
